# sharedApplication() Doesn't working in Today Extension in swift

Tags: ios, swift

i'm new to swift, i have created a today widget , and i added a button to that. in the Action of that button, i want to launch a url in safari, but "sharedApplication( )" doesn't working, i'm using this code in Normal view controller :

```js
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "facetime:mahdi@gmail.com")!)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

but its not working in Today App Extension.

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html) and [search Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934888/app-and-extension-use-core-data-error-sharedapplication-is-unavailable) before you waste bandwidth by asking a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `sharedApplication` from an app extension.

Today widgets can open urls using the `openUrl:completionHandler:` method on `NSExtensionContext`, so you could do:

```
extensionContext?.openURL(NSURL(string: "facetime:mahdi@gmail.com")!, completionHandler: nil)
```

You should be doing this in the tap handler for your button though, not in `viewDidLoad`.

But note that the apple documentation states:

> IMPORTANT
>
> Apple allows any Today widget to use the
>   openURL:completionHandler: method to open the widget’s own containing
>   app.
>
> If you employ this method to open other apps from your Today widget,
>   your App Store submission might entail additional review to ensure
>   compliance with the intent of Today widgets.
>
> To learn more, read App Store Review Guidelines and iOS Human
>   Interface Guidelines, linked to from [Apple’s App Review Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/) page

Answer (score 1):

This is [well documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html). There is no `sharedApplication()` in a Today extension; the code isn't running in your app. In this particular situation, you can communicate with the NSExtensionContext instead.

Comment: so, what i should do?